# How to disable null base queries on freeipa server

Tags: centos7, freeipa

I am using FreeIpa server 4.5 on CentOS 7.4. Now I want to disable Null Base queries on Ipa server. Please help. how i can do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is basically disabling an anonymous bind. This happens when bind event happens with user to the LDAP server without any authentication.

You should be able to disable this `nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access` setting which is in the `cn=config` entry of the LDAP.